# Is it possible to create a new css property?

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a new property in CSS? For example, say you're developing a control that displays a photo and you want to add a property to css to control what style frame to have around the photo. Something like:

```
#myphoto { frame-style: fancy }
```

Is there some way to do this in a cross browser compatible manner, and how would you define whether the style inherits or not?

EDIT: It's a custom control - your JS code would deal with the style - I'm not expecting the browser to magically know what to do. I want the user to be able to style the control with CSS instead of JS.

Comment: your example is like from real CSS specification :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, why not. Check this out as an example: http://bililite.com/blog/2009/01/16/jquery-css-parser/

You may also be able to get away with using CSS classes instead of properties. Not sure if that works for what you're doing.

Comment: It can't prevent me from going to bed at ridiculous hours of the night, apparently.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Browsers interpret CSS based on how their [layout engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layout_engine) are coded to do so.

Unless you took an existing open source engine like WebKit or Gecko, added custom code to handle your custom CSS and made a browser that used your customized layout engine. But then only your implementation would understand your custom CSS.

Re your edit: it'd depend on whether you're able to read that style somehow. Typically browsers just instantly discard any properties they don't recognize, and CSS is not normally reachable by JavaScript because CSS code is not part of the DOM.

Or you could look at [Jordan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787543/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-css-property/5787608#5787608).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answers my question. I noticed that the solutions for distributing elements horizontally provided by flex lack certain desired behavior. space-around comes closest to it, but if you want the outermost elements to be the same distance from the container as each inner element is from each other, then you seem to be out of luck. --I'd set out to write the behavior in javascript myself, but if what you say is true, it could not be implemented anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd prefer a straight JavaScript solution that uses no JS libraries, you could use the query string of a background-image to keep "custom properties" inside your CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">hello</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#foo {
   background: url('images/spacer.gif?bar=411');
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
getCustomCSSProperty('foo', 'bar');
```

**Supporting JavaScript Functions**

```
function getCustomCSSProperty(elId, propName)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(elId);
    var bi = obj.currentStyle ? obj.currentStyle.backgroundImage : document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(obj, null).getPropertyValue('background-image');
    var biurl = RegExp('url\\(["\\\']?([^"\\\']+)["\\\']?\\)').exec(bi);
    return getParameterByName(propName, biurl[1]);
}

function getParameterByName(name, qs) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(qs);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/t2DYk/1/

**Explanation:**
http://refactorer.blogspot.com/2011/08/faking-custom-css-properties.html

I've tested the solution in IE 5.5-9, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari.